# Django snippet with logic

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

is there a way to create a Django snippet that has logic?

I think about something like contact template tag:

```
{% contact_form %}
```

with template:

```
<form action="send_contact_form" method="POST">...</form>
```

with logic:

```
def send_contact_form():
    ...
```

I want to be able to use it anywhere in my projects. It should work only by specifying 1 template tag... Do you know what I mean? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance, Etam.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom template tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/).